# Catch formcraft submit with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, formcraft

I am building a website in Wordpress, and I'm using the Formcraft plugin, as it's quite nice and easy to use.

I would like to send data to my mongoDB server API endpoint (I'm using mLab service), but unfortunately it doesn't load data on it after click.

So I thought I could add a jQuery script to the page to catch the click and the form field and send it to the server my way.

```
<button type="submit" class="button submit-button">
<span class="text ">Send request</span>
<span class="spin-cover">
<i style="color:" class="loading-icon icon-cog animate-spin"></i>
</span>
</button>
```

How can i do, only having the class of the field?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your last sentence really confused me about what your specific question is.

Comment: Sorry about that, I will try to rephrase. I come from php development, and usually in a POST request you retrieve your data through fields ids. I am not particularly expert of jQuery, but I researched and it looked similar.

Comment: PHP `$_POST` and `$_GET` fields are based on the queryString passed in the url or the body of the request.  Those query keys are based on the input field names for traditional form submits.  But regardless, I'm not sure what exactly you are asking about in this question.  Your title suggests you would be asking about how to bind an event handler for the submit event, but then your final sentence seems to go off topic, at least related to the title.

Comment: Yes, you got my question right. I have that code, and I cannot change it. Can i bind it to a jQuery listener?

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/  Sure you can bind a submit handler.  Though to do that it would be useful if you could include your form markup in the question as well and not just the button.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Taplar for the answers (and the patience).

I managed to find the answer I was looking for, I'll post it here if anyone will be looking for it.

It's easy to extend functionalities of the Formcraft plugin through jQuery.

Inspecting the source code generated by the plugin, is possible to see the way fields are done. 
They all have this thing in common: "data-field-id='fieldN'".

It's possible to get it simply adding to the Wordpress page this code:

```
jQuery("[data-field-id='field1']").click(function($){
        alert('hi');
    });
```

What I lacked was a proper knowledge of selectors.
I found good answers in the official documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)